# Caching related data

Tags: c#, sql-server, caching

I have some related entities which support cascade updatings/deletions (user, user roles, user's and role's permissions).
The app server uses it often and i need to implement fast access to it. For that purposes i gonna put it to the application cache.
The question is howto provide syncronization between DB and the cache when executing cascade operation over that data? For example, if i drop some role i also need to drop all that role permissions or if i drop a user i need to drop all its roles and their permissions.
I see a number of ways to support actual data in my cache but i see some disadvantages as well.. Please, tell me what is the best solution.

1. All cascade operations are made in database using triggers. The application receives notifications via `SqlCacheDependency` mechanism. Problem: what about whn server is heavy loaded? Would notifications be delayed and would it cost too much for DB/app server to serve many exact dependencies like "`select SomeField from DataTable where id = @x`"?
2. All cascade operations are made in the business layer of application. Every DB update/delete operation is followed by cache invalidation operation. The problem: doubled logic and high network traffic (many updates instead one)
3. Cascade operations in DB, cascade invalidations in cache using `CacheDependency`. The problem: doubled logic.

What is the good solution?
Thank you!

Comment: > 2) All cascade operations are made in the business layer of application >> I mean data acess layer

Comment: Does Entity Framework provides such functionality so it automatically doing cascade changes as well?

Answer (score 0):

how about using an ORM?
personally I use [nHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx), which comes with [caching](http://ayende.com/blog/3976/nhibernate-2nd-level-cache) and cascading built-in, so you don't even have to worry about that (+ of course, many many other features to make your life a whole lot easier).

otherwise, I would definitely NOT go with option #1 or #3 since they introduces application logic into your storage layer.
a clever implementation of option #2 - application sending delete commands to the DB should not hinder your performance.

Comment: thanks for reply. In the option #2 i'll anyway need to execute many single updates/deletes over network for every related entity. Do you think it's a good idea?

Comment: why for every related entity? If you're deleting a role, than your query would be `delete from permissions where role_id = ...` which is just one query. and anyway- until you've proved it to be a performance problem, you shouldn't treat it as one. *'premature optimization is the root of all evil`* http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: i got you :) So... My RolePermission entity will have both Delete and DeleteByRole business-layer methods which must contain cache entry invaldations. Right?

Comment: and if i do a social network, and i'm deleting user, i should also delete a lot of related entities such like his roles, groups, posts, comments, favorites, bookmarks, friendships etc. I'm OK about not to optimize before there is a need :) but this point is still not clean to me

Comment: something to that effect. also note that you can send multiple delete / update statements to your DB in one round-trip, so, again- there's no impact on performance.